# Setup multiple environment for angular application

Tags: angular

I have an angular application for which I need to set multiple environments. My application has more than one clusters and for each cluster I have to set multiple environments for build purposes. By running `ng build --configuration abc` build file is created successfully, but whenever I run my index file on local there are no API hits. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by installing http server in the build file using **npm i -g http-server** command and then ran the command *http-server* which gave me a port. I just pasted that port in web browser which worked successfully. Thanks ChatGPT.